# Built-in laptop webcam won't focus (auto or manual)

Tags: arch-linux, camera, v4l

I have a Lenovo Yoga 900 running Arch.  The built-in webcam is detected (`lsusb` names it Lenovo EasyCamera) and works, for the most part.  It captures video and seems to largely work fine with every application that I've tried.  However, the image is always badly out of focus, and there seems to be no way - manual or automatic - to control the focus.  Here's the output from `v4l2-ctl -l`:

```
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=2
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2500 max=6500 step=10 default=4500 value=4500 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=50 value=50
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1
```

These are also the only user controls which appear in the `qv4l2` GUI interface.  I am fairly sure that the hardware supports auto-focus, since the last time I tested it the camera had this functionality working under Windows.

Is there any way to add a control - specifical a focus control - to a V4L2-supported camera?  I don't care if it's auto focus or manual focus, I would just like to not be blurry.

Comment: did you clean the lens?

Comment: @jsotola lol, yeah. It's definitely just the focus: items held very close to the lens are clear and in focus, but things at normal webcam distance (e.g. my face) are never in focus

Comment: something inside the laptop lid may have shifted ... does the focus change when you tap the back of the camera with your fingers?

Comment: @realityChemist did you find a solution to this? I'm dealing with the exact same issue.

Comment: @sebpardo Unfortunately I never did.  I ended up getting a new laptop for other reasons, but it may be worth getting an external webcam (unsatisfying, I know).